# How to only allow UpdateItem on existing dynamoDB resources?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Can DynamoDB `UpdateItem` be passed an option so that calling `UpdateItem` on non-existing items fails?

Currently `UpdateItem` happily creates a new item if partition-key doesn't exist. I want an error instead in this particular situation.

Of course I can do a get prior to updateItem and only do an updateItem on existence but that is less performant / more cumbersome.

Comment: Would it be less performant? Have you tested this out? I don't know myself but I'm curious.

Comment: No doubt. There's at least one less roundtrip plus , in my case, one less pass through Api gateway. On top of that dynamodb is likely able to do the conditional put faster then a get plus put separately but that last part is an assumption for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a conditional update using a **ConditionExpression**.

The conditional updates API is quite powerful but in your case, you'll want to build a condition expression that checks whether the item that you're trying to update exits using a conditional expression on the item's partition key (and range key if your table uses one).

Since you didn't specify a programming language, the best place to start is [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html).

Comment: Ah that's pretty powerful!

Comment: What is ConditionExpression syntax to be used in PHP

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, you must set `ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(<your key attribute name>)"`.

That will fail if key related Item does not exist - DynamoDB search the key related Item, doesn't find any, and all the `attribute_exists` [condition function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions) calls fail.

In opposite, if the Item exists, it always has the key attribute, so `attribute_exists(key)` returns true.